# ActiveRecord not using overridden table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Sorry if this has been asked before. I am new to ActiveRecord and working with a remote legacy sqlserver database outside the rails world. This is how the 2 tables are set up

```
**Student**                             **LookupStatusCode**
Identifier(PK)   StatusCodeId            Id(PK)    Code   Name        
1234               2                      1       4     Studying maths 
3456               1                      2       6     Studying science
```

This is how I have set up my models

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base     
  self.table_name "Student" #use singular table name                
  belongs_to :status_code, foreign_key: 'StatusCodeId'                  
end

class StatusCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name "LookupStatusCode" #use singular table name
  has_many :students
end
```

How do I find all students that are for example, studying science?

I tried-
`Student.joins(:status_code).where(status_code: {Name: 'Studying science'})`
but it seems to be using `status_code.Name` in the where clause instead of `LookupStatusCode.Name`

Here's the SQL it generates. Please note that the WHERE part of the sql doesn't use the overridden table name.

```
SELECT [student].* FROM [student] INNER JOIN [LookupStatusCode] ON [LookupStatusCode].[Id] = [student].[StatusCodeId] WHERE [status_code].[Name] = N'5'
```

Have I set up everything correctly or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you print what sql activerecord generates?

`Student.joins(:status_code).where(status_code: {Name: 'Studying science'}).to_sql`

Comment: Could you please provide the all the SQL output from console? You say it seems to be using `status_code.Name`, so you should be getting a SQL exception. Try `Student.joins(:status_code).where(status_codes: {Name: 'Studying science'})`.

Comment: @NikitaMisharin Here's the sql `"SELECT [student].* FROM [student] INNER JOIN [LookupStatusCode] ON [LookupStatusCode].[Id] = [student].[StatusCodeId] WHERE [status_code].[Name] = N'5'"`. Please note the where clause. Seems to be not picking up the table name

Comment: @fbelanger still get the same Invalid SQL error. Please see my sql above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work

`Student.joins(:status_code).where('LookupStatusCode' => {Name: 'Studying science'})`

**Update:**

As an alternative you can also build a query with arel.

First, you need to add `include ArelHelpers::ArelTable` into `StatusCode` model.

Then, you'll be able to construct the following query

`Student.joins(:status_code).where(StatusCode['Name'].eq('Studying science'))`

Comment: Yes Nikita. This works but since I have defined the new table name, I don't want to specify it again in the query. Should it not be picking up the defined table name like it does in the ON part of the sql? Or may be there's an alternative way to get the result I am looking for? Thanks.

Comment: There is a way to do it. Though, I can't provide an example right now. I'll update the answer as soon as I can *(in twelve hours or so)*